# SQL - Check if overlapping working hour exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following database schema (where day value `0=mon,1=tue,2=wed` and so on)

[image]

And the following input

```
{
    "day": 3,
    "start_time": "15:00",
    "end_time": "17:30"
},
{
    "day": 5
    "start_time": "08:00",
    "end_time": "12:00"
}
```

I want to find if input value contains any overlapping record from the database. (note that in my case, I can have multiple start_time, end_time for a given day)

Here is what I tried.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(id) AS total_count
FROM
    working_hour
WHERE (
    (day = 3 AND (start_time <= '15:00' AND end_time >= '17:30')) ||
    (day = 5 AND (start_time <= '08:00' AND end_time >= '12:00'))
) AND user_id = 1;
```

This return me total count of `0` whereas I am expecting `1` because on `day = 3` we have a matching overlapping record with id `5`

Where am I going wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: This could get hairy.  Is there any reason why you are storing the day and time in separate columns?

Comment: I need to store the working hour of user, the application I am working on allows to book a calendar for the user based on availability hence the user has to first define the availability.

Comment: Isn't it normal to define and store business hours the way I am storing? check these examples https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19545597/way-to-store-various-shop-opening-times-in-a-database, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464898/best-way-to-store-working-hours-and-query-it-efficiently

Comment: I am willing to know if there are any better/alternative approach.

Comment: Can an input range span across multiple days, or is it guaranteed that an input would always be within a single day?

Comment: Input range can be more than one. I added only one for now to make it bit simpler.

Comment: You should instead just show us the real problem.  As it stands now, you will end up receiving an incomplete answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the logic you want is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_count
FROM working_hour
WHERE user_id = 1 AND
      ((day = 3 AND start_time <= '17:30' AND end_time >= '15:00') OR
       (day = 5 AND start_time <= '12:00' AND end_time >= '8:00')
      ) ;
```